# Python3 Program Suddenly Given Error Messages Regarding Request Code

Tags: pi-3, python-3

I have been running a python3 program that is using request and it has been running fine for the past month.
Today when I rebooted my Pi Model 3B+, I am getting these errors when I restarted the program.

I tried going back to a previous SD card backup and even changed SD cards but to no avail.

Do I have a pi that has a hardware problem or is there a fix available?

I have a model 3B pi that I use as backup and this program works fine on that model.  I compared the --int--.py program on both of the pi's and the code is the same. Any help would be appreciated.

the following are the errors:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 rain.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 32, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rain.py", line 10, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    vendored('urllib3')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 35, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from six.moves.http_client import (
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1218, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 91, in <module>
    import ipaddress
  File "/home/pi/ipaddress.py", line 6, in <module>
    from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/auth.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .compat import urlparse, str, basestring
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/compat.py", line 58, in <module>
    from urllib.request import parse_http_list, getproxies, proxy_bypass
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1286, in <module>
    if hasattr(http.client, 'HTTPSConnection'):
AttributeError: module 'http' has no attribute 'client'
```

Script

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import time
import re
import os
import requests
import csv
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

from urllib.request import urlopen  # in python3
import smtplib

#  Common Credentials

c=open('/home/pi/credentials.dat','r')
lines = c.readlines()
username = lines[0].rstrip('\n')
password = lines[1].rstrip('\n')
usernameG = lines[2].rstrip('\n')
passwordG = lines[3].rstrip('\n')
ipaddress = lines[4].rstrip('\n')
c.close

#time.sleep(600)  #  This is to be sure the ISY has stabilized after a Power Outage

###  This logic is to get the Total Rain Today from Climate Module and send to ISY

today = date.today()
t = time.localtime()  # gives you an actual struct_time object
h = t.tm_hour  # gives you the hour part as an integer
m = t.tm_min
climate_Rain = 0.0

if today.month >= 5 and today.month <= 10:
    climate = requests.get('ipaddress/rest/climate', auth=(username, password))
    time.sleep(15)
    temp = requests.get('ipaddress/rest/vars/get/1/67', auth=(username, password))
    time.sleep(15)
    climate_Rain = 0.0

    root = ET.fromstring(temp.content)

    for svar in root.iter('climate'):
        climate_Rain = float(svar.find('Total_Rain_Today').text[:2])

    #print(datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'), climate_Rain)

    r = requests.get('ipaddress/rest/vars/set/1/67/' + str(climate_Rain),
                    auth=(username, password))
    time.sleep(15)
    #print(r)
    r = requests.get('ipaddress/rest/vars/init/1/67/' + str(climate_Rain),
                      auth=(username, password))
    time.sleep(15)
    #print(r)
```

Comment: Does the SD card from the 3B+ work correctly in the 3B?  (I'd guess, without enough info, that the card in the 3B+ is corrupted somehow.)

Comment: So, is this your problem: `ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3'` ?

Comment: M. Rostami.  Yes it appears so.  What is strange is that this program has worked without any issues for at least a month.  I am not sure how to fix this error.       Bob Brown. The SD card does not work in the Model 3B.  I get the same error.  However, if I run the program on the Model 3 B with its own SD card, it runs without an error.  I used a new SD card and an old back up but no change in the 3B+.  I appreciate your comments.  Thanks